# how can i create a azure VM in a specific cloud service?

Tags: linux, azure, cloud, virtual-machine

When I do (in linux command line):

```
azure vm create Machine 0b11de9248dd4d87b18621318e037d37__RightImage-CentOS-7.0-x64-v14.2.1 USER passuser --location "West Europe"
```

there is always a line with "+ Creating cloud service"

how can i do without creating a new cloud service and use one that just exist?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-command-line-tools/), please try with `-c` or `-connect` option.

From the documentation page:

> **vm create [options]    [password]**
>
> This command creates a new Azure virtual machine. By default, each
>   virtual machine (vm) is created in its own cloud service; **however, you
>   can specify that a virtual machine should be added to an existing
>   cloud service through use of the -c option as documented here**.